# geometric mean in Matlab for a specific time interval

Tags: matlab, time-series, moving-average

say that I have a matrix (NX2) where the first column's elements are the number of seconds (since midnight) and the second column is stock returns associated to associated to the seconds. How can I use the function geomean and compute the geometric returns for a specific time interval? Say the geomean returns at *every* minute interval? The problem is that I might have say 4 stock returns in some specific minute interval and sometime 10 returns in another interval. If I extract all the trades by minutes, the numbers of returns registered in each minute interval will not be the same.
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB: compute mean of each 1-minute interval of a time-series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323031/matlab-compute-mean-of-each-1-minute-interval-of-a-time-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the time in minutes (since midnight) as an integer, you can use my [consolidator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354-consolidator) function and geomean to compute what you need, and it is vectorized. Just download it from the file exchange.

[Consolidator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354-consolidator) will return a vector of the times where it found any data in a given minute, and a geometric mean of returns over each of those times.

Comment: Ya I have to take a closer look to this consolidator function. Otherwise I can do the following:data = [(1:130)', randi(100,130,1)];
out = accumarray(ceil(data(:,1)/60),data(:,2),[],@geomean,NaN);

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple `arrayfun`:

```
>> n = [15 1;25 2;67 3; 99 4;182 5] #% example data

n =
 #% t(s)   val  
    15     1
    25     2
    67     3
    99     4
   182     5

>> t1=0:60:240;
>> t2=t1+60;
>> arrayfun(@(t1,t2) geomean(n( n(:,1)>t1 & n(:,1)<=t2, 2)), t1,t2)

ans =

    1.4142    3.4641       NaN    5.0000       NaN
```

`t1` and `t2` are just vectors of the start and end times of your windows of interest. Here, I've made them be contiguous 60-second intervals; however they could be whatever you want.  Non-contiguous, overlapping, you name it.

The anonymous function captures the matrix `n` as it exists when `arrayfun` is called, and creates a logical index into the rows of the matrix for each `t1,t2` pair.

Comment: I should have been more clear though in my question: I have multiple days stack on over the other. For intance: all stock returns per second for Sept.02 and then Sept.03. I have to find out how not to accumulate geomean returns combining multiple days at the same time.

Comment: The most straightforward thing to do in that case is recalculate the time of the transactions so they all are referenced from a single start date.  If you want to start the clock at 12:00AM Sept. 02, add 24*60*60 seconds to all the trades on Sept. 03, and so on.

Comment: that's what I already have for the seconds. Good! Would you know if there is a way for me to store beside the geomean vector answers from which minute and date the geomean was computed? THANKS

Comment: In the solution I've suggested above, the start time and end time for each of the elements in the `geomean` vector are given by `t1` and `t2`.  So you don't actually have to do anything more... the information is there already.

Comment: thanks a lot! now I am also trying to learn it how to do it in SAS!